# How to navigate and passing props at the same component in react navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I tried to navigate my `App` component to `GamePlay` component, here's my `App.js` looks like.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


// Import my own components
import GamePlay from './components/GamePlay';
import {data} from './components/Stage/Stage';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
        > 

            <Stack.Screen name="Game Play">
              {() => <GamePlay data={data}/>}
            </Stack.Screen>
        
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

and this is my `GamePlay` component looks like.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function GamePlay({navigation}, props) {

    const ToHome = () => {
        navigation.navigate("Home Screen")
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ToHome}>
                <Text>Go Home</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
                <Text>this is gameplay</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

but why when I do `console.log(props.data)` in the GamePlay component It says `undefined`? I'm confuse how to pass navigation with props in a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small working example: [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/bossy-donuts)

try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default 
function GamePlay({navigation, data}) {
    console.log(data)
    const ToHome = () => {
        navigation.navigate("Home Screen")
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ToHome}>
                <Text>Go Home</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
                <Text>this is gameplay</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

also avoid keeping space while naming screens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to pass props from when you declare the route in the stack.

You can use initialParams for that like so:

```
<Stack.Screen component={GamePlay} name="GamePlay" initialParams={{data:data}} />
```

then write your GamePlay component as such:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function GamePlay({navigation, route}, props) {

    const ToHome = () => {
        navigation.navigate("Home Screen")
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ToHome}>
                <Text>Go Home</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
                <Text>this is gameplay</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

and console.log(route.params). Should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

navigation.navigate("Home Screen",{param1:'123456'})

Answer (score 0):

try to put {navigation,data} insted of {navigation}, props)